# The [specific] tag seems useless

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-block-request

The tag [specific](/questions/tagged/specific) has been applied to 112 pretty random questions just because the word happens to be a part of them. It doesn't seem to add any value, it's too common that a question applies to a "specific" situation or "specific" data needs processing.

Comment: Would you say that [tag:specific], is **not** specific?

Comment: Specific is so vague!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, no more questions are tagged with this. It will die within 24 hours.

Comment: The New Tag Deletionist Cabal assures you that the tag will remain *quite dead*.

Answer (score 4):

I browsed through them, and I don't see a single question where that tag adds anything. It should be burninated with extreme prejudice IMO.

Answer (score 4):

Since:

1. It has no wiki summary
2. It has no followers
3. It isn't being used appropriately

There is no reason to keep it.

Comment: Even if it had followers, those followers are better off without their tag as they know not what they are following. Exterminate.